# When multiple monsters enter a Vortex during a turn do multiple Dunwich tokens get added?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-dunwich-horror

From the Dunwich Horror rule book:

> For each monster returned to the cup in this fashion, **raise the terror
>   level by one.** In addition, if there are fewer than three Dunwich
>   Horror tokens on the Dunwich Horror track, **add one Dunwich Horror
>   token to the track.**

Does this mean if three monsters move onto a vortex in one monster movement phase that three Dunwich Horror tokens are added (if none are there) or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording specifies that this action is in **addition** to raising the terror level.

The rules does not state that you add one Dunwich Horror token for each monster added. After increasing the terror level, if there a fewer than 3 tokens, add one token only

Comment: Do you have a source for this ruling? I think the issue is that the wording in the rule book is ambiguous (that being said, I do interpret it the same way as you)

Comment: No source... I scoured the FAQ and couldnt find a corresponding ruling for this particular rule